# Armazenar valores de entrada em Java

Tags: java, array

Preciso armazenar valores com mais de uma entrada. Se um programa solicita 10 entradas, eu devo armazenar em 10 variáveis? No caso as entradas são do tipo `Int`.

Comment: Essa é uma dúvida para programadores muito iniciantes. A resposta vai depender muito do objetivo de armazenar as 10 entradas.

Comment: Utilize um Array, ou outra estrutura de dado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o problema estava nas estruturas de controle e não no armazenamento de variáveis.

Comment: @D.rosario A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos, terá assim que aceitar a resposta).

Answer (score 4):

Sim, deve, mas entenda o que é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

A dúvida não fala sobre que valores serão entrados, mas é provável que estas variáveis sejam do tipo `int`, já que para exercícios assim costuma pedir apenas valores numéricos inteiros.

Porém o mais provável é que espera-se que use um *array*. Uma variável do tipo *array* é aquela que armazena outras variáveis em sequência. Então teremos 11 variáveis, 1 para o *array* e 10 para os inteiros.

Em linguagens tipadas, como o Java, todas variáveis possuem tipos em tudo. Então tem um *array* de inteiros.

Quando estamos usando um *array* estamos falando de acessar um valor que depende de variações: uma é o *array* e outra é o dado em si. Então para acessar um *array* basta usar o nome da variável, mas para acessar o valor é necessário usar o nome da variável do *array* e o índice que indica qual variável dele será usada.

Então vamos criar o *array* do tipo `int` com 10 posições.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

Agora para acessar a primeira variável dele usamos:

```
array[0]
```

Para a segunda:

```
array[1]
```

Até a última:

```
array[9]
```

Isso é como acessar `array0`, `array1`, `array9`, mas se usasse os nomes assim o índice não poderia variar e isso deixa a aplicação pouco flexível. Com o índice é possível usar uma variável nele, assim:

```
array[i]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Storing.java).

Que posição está pegando? Aquela que a variável `i` indicar, varia, e esta é a beleza da computação. Assim você pode manipular 10 variáveis em até uma linha fazendo um laço de repetição.

Não está acostumando com *array*, laço (*loop*), essas coisas? Tem bastante informação aqui no site que pode te ajudar, dá uma pesquisada.